# What I must change to make a fadeIn on div and fadOut when scroll out of this element?

Tags: javascript

I was changed one line:

```
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, duration);
```

to scroll to the div position:

```
  $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(".product-single__title").offset().top},
        'slow');
     return false;
```

It's working good, but I need to move animate position to div element too..

P.S. Sorry for my English and thanks for the help.

This one is a default snippet.

```
{% comment %} 
      Reduce below value if you need the back to the top button to appear higher up on the page. 
      That value is in pixels.
    {% endcomment %}
    {% assign vertical_offset_for_trigger = 300 %}
    {% comment %} 
      Vertical offset from bottom of browser for the position of the button.
    {% endcomment %}
    {% assign position_from_bottom = '4em' %}
    <a href="#" title="Back to the top" class="back-to-top">
      <span>Back to the top</span> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up fa-2x"></i> 
    </a>
    {{ '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
    <style>
    .back-to-top {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: {{ position_from_bottom }};
      right: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #999;
      background-color: #eee;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 0.3em;
      display: none;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 60000;
    }
    .back-to-top i {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .back-to-top span {
      padding-left: 0.5em;
    }
    .back-to-top i + span {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    .back-to-top:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #555;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
     jQuery(function($) {
       var offset = {{ vertical_offset_for_trigger }};
       var duration = 500;
       $(window).scroll(function() {
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
           $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
         } 
         else {
           $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
         }
       });
       $('.back-to-top').unbind('click.smoothscroll').bind('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, duration);
         return false;
       })
     });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Just use a plugin rather than writing the whole code yourself  , https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the position on the page where you want the action to happen using pageXOffset, pageYOffset and scrollTop if that is what you need.

If you want to apply it to another element you can change the selector, in this case, 
    $('.back-to-top') to your own selector for the div you want to use 
    $('.yourDivElement').

Could you please explain a little more what you want to achieve?
Are these comments yours or do they belong to the original script?

Comment: This is a simple button to the top, but I struggle to customize for my needs. :) Thinking that this line must be changed:  if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {

Comment: You can omit the comments in the code but it would be useful to see the HTML in order to understand your question. There are similar questions dealing with scrolling elements here on StackOverflow have a look there too.